# How to create a simple Cron (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

After several different attempts I've created a cron task which runs the following file every minute - this file is called cron.php:

```
    <?php
      echo file_get_contents('http://website.com/search/all');
    ?>
```

**search** is my controller, **all** is my function.

When accessing this file through terminal like so, the file works correctly and expected:

```
 php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php
```

However, as soon as I schedule it inside **crontab -e** it doesn't run correctly (if at all) and doesn't show any errors. This is the contents of **crontab -e**:

```
* * * * * php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/brickmulesite/public/cron.php
```

When I look through my cron log (**grep cron /var/log/syslog**) this is what I see:

```
Jan 27 13:55:01 websitename CRON[22231]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 13:56:01 websitename CRON[22237]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 13:57:01 websitename CRON[22241]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 13:58:01 websitename CRON[22247]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 13:59:01 websitename CRON[22260]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:00:01 websitename CRON[22266]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:01:01 websitename CRON[22270]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:02:01 websitename CRON[22274]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:03:02 websitename CRON[22278]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:04:01 websitename CRON[22363]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:05:01 websitename CRON[22367]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:06:01 websitename CRON[22372]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:07:01 websitename CRON[22376]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
Jan 27 14:08:01 websitename CRON[22383]: (root) CMD (php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php)
```

It appears the cron is running but isn't running the code in the file. What am I missing?

I know I should be able to run it using the following but that didn't work either so I wanted to simplify the issue:

```
php -f /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/index.php search all
```

Comment: `php -f /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/index.php search/all` should work if your `Search.php` controller is directly in your `controllers` folder. Do you get any errors in your `error_log`? Also keep in mind you might use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` for your database host.

Comment: Hi @ArkoElsenaar - the `Search.php` file is directly inside the `controllers` folder.  The error_log is empty...

Comment: where do you expect to see the output when you run it from cron?

Comment: Hi @ScottSaunders - The file should send out an email and write to a database. Neither happens from the cron but do when accessed via CLI as `php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

You'll notice I'm using **ServerPilot** as part of my website. Their platform allows me to choose which version of php my web app should run. Anyway...

The fix was found on this website: 
https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-use-the-php-cli.html

What I needed to do was change the PHP call inside the cron so that it read:

```
* * * * * php5.6-sp /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php
```

Note the **php5.6-sp**

I imagine this is very specific to ServerPilot users.

Answer (score 0):

use complete path like

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Hi @recycler - When I run the command the following command from CLI it works fine. I see now reason why it wouldn't from inside the cron. `php /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/websitename/public/cron.php`

Comment: you run php from bash. bash has environement variables. cron does run it on system level and has no system variables. so the path is not known. "php" would be executed in root dir. only bash knows that it is in /usr/bin/ or /bin/ or ...

Answer (score 0):

simply use this with curl

curl "http://www.nameofdomain.com/controllername/functionname"

in Command textbox